# How to echo tty1 after displaying an image via fbi?

Tags: tty, fbi

I can echo to `/dev/tty1`:

```
echo "hello" > /dev/tty1
```

I can display an image (while booting or not):

```
fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a test.png
```

I can display the image after printing "hello" to the console, but I can not print anything after displaying an image. How can I print to the console after displayin an image?

Answer (score 1):

`killall fbi` solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly this parameter `-T 1` does? I could not find it in the manual page.

I've tested your example here, and I've reached the same behaviour. The solution was simply to remove the `-T 1` part.

Comment: It's [something undocumented](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=fbi+-T+1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=KH0lVsX4AYaVaIPPrqAM#q=%22fbi+-T+1%22+undocumented). However, I tried what you suggested and system is stucked while booting. I fixed by removing the storage, mount it on another machine, restore the `-T 1` part. Interesting :)

Comment: `killall fbi` solved the problem for now

Comment: The man page on my system says `-T n, --vt n` `Start on virtual console n.`.  Debian Sid, `fbi_2.10-2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that later. They say there is nothing mentioned about `-T` parameter in the man page, but explained in the help page.